# subset columns among millions of columns with bash script

Tags: shell, bigdata

I have a huge table, with 13 rows and over l00 million columns. I am going to select 10 million columns from those. And I know the indexing of the to-be-selected columns. Can I achieve this goal through bash script?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  **awk**, **sort**, and a variety of other basic UNIX commands have column-selection capabilities.  Depending on your table formatting, a parametrized regular expression might be the most effective solution for you.

Details depend on your required input and output formats.  The size of the data rows suggests a pipelined application rather than a line-by-line processor.

I hope this gets you started writing your code.

Comment: I didnot get it. The column index is not continuous. How can I read the column index from another file to pass it to the awk command as an array and then just print iterating the numbers in the array?

Comment: Please edit the refined requirements into the original question.  I'll work on the problem over my meal break in a few hours.